# How do I retrieve rows of a df using a vector as a key to match to a specific column while preserving order and duplicates?

Tags: r

Normally I would do this sort of thing with

```
df2 <- subset(df1, df$ID %in% vector)
```

but this doesn't preserve duplicates; or

```
df2 <- df[vector,]
```

but this doesn't match the vector with the `df$column` just the rows

Here is a sample `data.frame`

```
  ID      Fruit     Color
1  2      Apple     Amber
2  5    Bannana      Blue
3  7     Cherry      Cyan
4  9       Date Dandelion
5 14 Elderberry     Earth
6 15        Fig   Fuchsia
7 21      Grape     Green
```

and here is a sample vector

```
vector <- c(5,5,5,7,2,14,14,14)
```

and here is the output I would like

```
  ID      Fruit Color
1  5    Bannana  Blue
2  5    Bannana  Blue
3  5    Bannana  Blue
4  7     Cherry  Cyan
5  2      Apple Amber
6 14 Elderberry Earth
7 14 Elderberry Earth
8 14 Elderberry Earth
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try matching on the ID

```
df[match(vector, df$ID), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the vector in a dataframe and do a merge:

```
df2 = data.frame(ID = vector)
df2 = merge(df2, df, by = "ID", sort = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
> df2
  ID      Fruit Color
1  5    Bannana  Blue
2  5    Bannana  Blue
3  5    Bannana  Blue
4  7     Cherry  Cyan
5  2      Apple Amber
6 14 Elderberry Earth
7 14 Elderberry Earth
8 14 Elderberry Earth
```

If you're using `dplyr` then `left_join` also seems to work, but keeping the sort order does not seem to be documented so I'm not sure if it can be relied on 100%:

```
df3 = data.frame(ID = vector) %>%
    left_join(df, by = "ID")
```